# Prisma get latest updated value with duplicates row

Tags: typescript, postgresql, prisma

i want to select a table and get the latest time they registered,
i want to retrieve it with duplicate value, without group by or distinct

something like this

Table

```sql
ID  |  Name  | Time_Registered            |
1   |   A    | 2022-11-20 04:21:14.679    |
2   |   A    | 2022-11-21 05:21:14.679    |
3   |   B    | 2022-11-20 06:21:14.679    |
4   |   B    | 2023-11-22 08:21:14.679    |
5   |   D    | 2023-11-20 04:21:14.679    |
```

Expected result

```sql
ID  |  Name  | Time_Registered            | Last_Registered
1   |   A    | 2022-11-20 04:21:14.679    | 2022-11-21 05:21:14.679
2   |   A    | 2022-11-21 05:21:14.679    | 2022-11-21 05:21:14.679
3   |   B    | 2022-11-20 06:21:14.679    | 2023-11-22 08:21:14.679
4   |   B    | 2023-11-22 08:21:14.679    | 2023-11-22 08:21:14.679
5   |   D    | 2023-11-20 04:21:14.679    | 2023-11-20 04:21:14.679
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Windowed](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) version of the aggregate function `max()`. See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/hc2YnhT2).

```
select t.* 
     , max(t.time_registered) over(partition by t.name) "Last_Registered" 
  from <table> t
 order by id;
```